# Как сделать чтобы фон блока растягивался на всю ширину экрана?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Я хочу сделать чтобы фон блока растягивался на всю ширину экрана, но при этом контент был в границах фиксированной ширины, то есть вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую Bootstrap v5.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

блок на всю ширину

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  ...
</div>
```

в него вложить

```
<div class="container">
...
</div>
```

получится так

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col">
          ...
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: не срабатывает так( вот скрин https://dropmefiles.com/v2p4i

Comment: не срабатывает. попробуйте пожалуйста сами, в ответе сделайте вставку HTML

Comment: сейчас гляну и отвечу

Comment: извиняюсь, это у меня был косяк. все сработало! спасибо вам огромное!

Comment: всегда пожалуйста )